# How to fix NullPointerException? (Android SDK, Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I feel like this is a simple problem that I'm somehow missing but I can't for the life of me figure out what's going wrong with this code. Every time this class loads I get a NullPointerException

```
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): Process: john.brian.adlibs, PID: 2144
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start            activity ComponentInfo{john.brian.adlibs/john.brian.adlibs.StoryDisplay}:         java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at john.brian.adlibs.StoryDisplay.onCreate(StoryDisplay.java:25)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     ... 11 more
```

and, after heavy Googling, I'm pretty sure everything is defined.

```
public class StoryDisplay extends Activity{ 

TextView storyView;
Button sdBackToStoryList;
ScrollView scrollView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.story_display);
    setVariables(); 
    String story = getIntent().getExtras().getString("storyFinal");    
    storyView.setText(story);
    sdBackToStoryList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent viewChooseStory = new Intent(StoryDisplay.this, ChooseStory.class);
            startActivity(viewChooseStory);

        }
    });
    }

private void setVariables() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sdBackToStoryList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStoryDisplayBackToStoryList);
    storyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStoryDisplayStory);
    scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svStoryDisplay);
}
```

}

And the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:padding="0dp" >
 <com.google.ads.AdView  android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3337976893531833/3006951709"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, emulator-5554"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                   />
 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_weight="10"
android:padding="20dp" >

<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/svStoryDisplay"   
android:layout_height="350dp">
<TextView
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:id="@+id/tvStoryDisplayStory"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left" />
</ScrollView>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/bStoryDisplayBackToStoryList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="@string/backToStoryList"
     />
```

The only thing I can think of is the string that the storyView is set to, which is defined with the same button that starts the StoryDisplay in another class:

```
String storyFinal =  new String("String goes here");

            Intent teleport = new Intent(SadLibs.this, StoryDisplay.class);
            teleport.putExtra("storyFinal",storyFinal);
            startActivity(teleport);        

            Intent viewChooseStory = new Intent(SadLibs.this, StoryDisplay.class);
            startActivity(viewChooseStory);
```

The error appears to be in the line:

```
storyView.setText(story);
```

Again, I'm sure this is an incredibly simple issue I'm just missing and I feel incredibly stupid for having this issue but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please update with the actual error message including the stack-trace and point out the line that gets NPE

Comment: String storyFinal =  new String("String goes here");

Comment: Please edit your question and include the stack trace.  The line you have shown in the comment cannot generate an NPE.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-19 17:40:35.967: E/AndroidRuntime(2144):     at john.brian.adlibs.StoryDisplay.onCreate(StoryDisplay.java:25)` what is line 25?

Comment: Why are you creating two `Intents`?

Answer (score 0):

In the code below

```
Intent teleport = new Intent(SadLibs.this, StoryDisplay.class);
teleport.putExtra("storyFinal",storyFinal);
startActivity(teleport);        

Intent viewChooseStory = new Intent(SadLibs.this, StoryDisplay.class);
startActivity(viewChooseStory);
```

You add extra only once. If you don't add `storyFinal` extra, you will get NPE in the line

```
String story = getIntent().getExtras().getString("storyFinal");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String story = getIntent().getExtras().getString("storyFinal");
```

You need to check to see if the Intent or the Extras is NULL.

```
if (getIntent() != NULL) {
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != NULL) {
        story = getIntent().getExtras().getString("storyFinal");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct approach to avoid NPEs (tho I'd put both if statements in the same one), however it's not clear is the problem is not his own "logic", but we can't tell whether a null extra is OK in his app or not :)

Comment: When he creates the intent viewChooseStory, there are no extras added to the intent.... assuming those 2 snippets of code are from different parts of his application.

Comment: Yeah, it's really hard to tell without access to all the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check like this :

```
  if(storyView!=null)
  {
     storyView.setText(story);
  }
```

Just implement

```
sdBackToStoryList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStoryDisplayBackToStoryList);
storyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStoryDisplayStory);
scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svStoryDisplay);
```

in onCreate().

Hope this helps.